# Options for debugging a PyInstaller-packaged Python/PyQt app?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

The app works fine when run as script, and also compiled macOS executable through terminal. However, some things behave unexpectedly when I click it as an .app. How does one debug this, e.g. view print statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view print statements of a compiled PyInstaller app, you have to set `console=True` in your .spec file, and you should be running pyinstaller on the .spec file as opposed to the .py file.

That said, the pyinstaller auto-generated .spec file defaults to `console=True`, so I suspect that you're looking for how to run the binary directly on OSX.  To do that, you must run the binary that's located inside the .app bundle, as opposed to the app bundle, itself.

Every .app on OSX is actually a directory.  You'll find the binary in, for example:

```
myApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/myApplication
```

If you run that in a terminal, you will see the print statements echoed out to the terminal.

Top tip: almost every OSX app bundle follows this idea: < app_name >.app/Contents/MacOS/< actual_binary >